# Raspberry Pi listchanges errors when installing something new

Tags: installation, raspberry-pi, command-line-interface

Every time I try install something I get two errors:

`E: Sub-process /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10 returned an error code (1)`

`E: Failure running script /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10`

I have tried installing multiple packages such as `sudo apt install arduino` but all return with the same error